# Unable to install the deepspeech library from pip. Can't find the module

Tags: pip, mozilla-deepspeech, p-lang

I am attempting to install the Deepspeech library for Python on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.

I've created a virtual environment and then run pip install deepspeech.  However, all I get back is the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech

I can access deepspeech on tbe Pypi website so I know it's there.  Could this have something to do with the fact that I'm running Python 3.10?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, it seems the latest release is for 3.9 as seen [in pip](https://pypi.org/project/deepspeech/#files) and [this issue](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/cp310-binary-release/94269) and [the release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases)

Perhaps try [installing another python version alongside 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569378/4935162).

To be fair, if I were you I'd probably spin up a virtual machine instead of messing with my daily driver's python installations. Or find a different, maintained library.

Intuitively, it *feels* wrong to install another version, as ubuntu (or linux in general?) uses python as part of it's operation. (also mentioned in attached answer). If the "python3"/"python" symlinks somehow get remapped to the old version, it's gonna be problematic. be careful!

Answer (score 0):

DeepSpeech, and the CI/CD pipeline that compiles the wheels for each Python version, [is no longer maintained](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/future-of-deepspeech-stt-after-recent-changes-at-mozilla/66191), and that's why it's not available for Python 3.10. It *might* be possible to compile it from source, but I suspect that due to its myriad dependencies - such as on an old version of TensorFlow - that it will be difficult to compile.

You may be better off working with a different STT product, such as Coqui's STT engine.